# Java net socket exception- Connection reset - How to fix from java

Tags: java, sockets, httpurlconnection

I have tried to execute the following snippet:

```java
URL obj = new URL(serviceLastURL);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("x-ibm-client-id", IrProperties.getXIBMClientId());
conn.setRequestProperty("x-ibm-client-secret", IrProperties.getXIBMClientSecret());
conn.setRequestProperty("OAuth-Token", accessToken); conn.setDoOutput(true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
    sb.append((char) c);
```

Once the connection fails abruptly, 
when I try to connect to the same `URL`, I got the following exception:

```
java.net.socketException - connection reset
```

How can I refresh the URL back with response?

And how can I prevent this exception?

Comment: Please provide the whole code block and not a short excerpt.

Comment: URL obj = new URL(serviceLastURL);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setRequestProperty("x-ibm-client-id", IrProperties.getXIBMClientId());
   conn.setRequestProperty("x-ibm-client-secret", IrProperties.getXIBMClientSecret());
   conn.setRequestProperty("OAuth-Token", accessToken);

   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
     sb.append((char) c);

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still cannot understand what do you mean by _the connection fails abruptly_? You are trying to perform a _GET_ request, then read the request result. When does the connection fail? How are you executing this snippet?

Comment: I am trying to get some data from REST Api call.sometimes this is hapenning.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the connection. Always close the connection after use.

Also, it may happen that the connection you are requesting is not available from the client side.

Comment: Hello Shankar, if I do this -   Will this gaurantee that this socket reset exceptio will not come -     finally {
   if (null != in) {
    try { in.close(); }
       catch (IOException ignore) {}
   }
   if(null != conn) {
    conn.disconnect();
    
   }
  }

Comment: in = inputStream,     conn is connection